# Cannot resolve the configured swagger-router handler: movie_get

Tags: node.js, swagger

I'm using Swagger with NodeJS, and when I test an example I have [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsVhT.png).

Here is my YAML:

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  version: "0.0.1"
  title: Hello World App
# during dev, should point to your local machine
host: localhost:10010
# basePath prefixes all resource paths 
basePath: /
# 
schemes:
  # tip: remove http to make production-grade
  - http
  - https
# format of bodies a client can send (Content-Type)
consumes:
  - application/json
# format of the responses to the client (Accepts)
produces:
  - application/json
paths:
  /movie:
    # our controller name
    x-swagger-router-controller: movie
    get:
      description: get the movies list
      # define the type of response for Success "200" and Error
      responses:
        "200":
          description: Success
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/GetMoviesListResponse"
        default:
          description: Error
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/ErrorResponse"
  /swagger:
    x-swagger-pipe: swagger_raw
# complex objects have schema definitions
definitions:
  GetMoviesListResponse:
    required:
      - movies
    properties:
      # The array of movies
      movies:
        type: array
        items: 
          type: object
          properties:
            id:
              type: string
            title:
              type: string
            year:
              type: number
  ErrorResponse:
    required:
      - message
    properties:
      message:
        type: string
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your YAML, and assuming you're using [swagger-tools](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-tools) with the options given in their tutorials, `x-swagger-router-controller: movie` will route any requests to `GET /movie` to a function called `get` exported from the module `/controllers/movie.js` in your project. Have you set that up?

Also check your swagger options to check that the correct controllers path is included, e.g. `` controllers: `${__dirname}`/controllers ``.